# What's the difference between $("<p>") and $("p")

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tags

We are currently learning jQuery in school and I don't get the difference between `$("<p>")` and `$("p")`. While I understand that `$("p")` searches for all `<p>` elements, I can't find anything about `$("<p>")` on the internet.

Here is the code we got from our teacher:

```
var p = $("<p>").text("This is section " + ($("p").size() + 1))
.attr("align", "right").css("color", "blue");
```

Comment: `$('<p>')` creates a new `p` DOMElement, while `$('p')` selects all the `p` DOMElements that currently exist in the DOM

Comment: Thank you, now this makes sense!

Comment: No problem. See the documentation for further details: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2

Comment: Well, in Italy highschools have specializations. My school has computer science as specialization, so we learn Java, C, HTML, JSP, JavaScript and a few smaller Addons of those. Alse we learn additianal topics like JUnit, how to write programming models and how computers work in general.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$("<p>")` will create a paragraph element and return it, whereas `$("p")` will select all the paragraph elements in the dom and return it.

```
var p = $("<p>").text("This is section " + ($("p").size() + 1))
.attr("align", "right").css("color", "blue");
```

This code can be dismantled like below,

```
var p = $("<p>"); //created a new Paragraph element
p.text("This is section " + ($("p").size() + 1)); //set text that displays the count of the created paragraph element.
p.attr("align", "right"); //set its attribute.
p.css("color", "blue"); //set its color.
```

Also your teacher, should not recommend you guys to use `.size()` since it was deprecated already. Use `.length` instead.

Comment: Thank you, now this makes sense!

Comment: @T.J.Crowder was a typo, written it correctly while explaining the code. Thanks for pointing. Also should i use document instead of DOM ? Both are correct isn't it?

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy: People use "DOM" where they mean "document" often enough that it's probably idiomatic, yeah. DOM is the technology and specification; the document is the document being displayed in the page. You can have a DOM element that isn't in any document (although it will be connected to a document). So I tend to use "document" when I'm talking about the tree being displayed in the page.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Well said TJ, I understood your point.